# R shiny: Subset data based on checkboxgroupinput

Tags: r, shiny

I want to sub set my data based on the columns selected dynamically by check-box input.
Is there any way in which I can make my input file globally available in my code
so that further operations can be easily performed.

Following is my code:

Server.R

```
    library(shiny)

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    dInput <- reactive({
       inFile <- input$file1
       if (is.null(inFile))
       return(NULL)

    finput <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=TRUE, sep=',',quote="'")
    fheaders <- names(finput) 
    return(fheaders)
    })


    output$choose_columns <- renderUI({
                       checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = dInput(),
                       selected = NULL)
    })


  # to observe in environment which columns are selected
  observe({ print(input$columns) })


  output$data_table <- renderTable({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    if(is.null(input$file1))
      return()

    # Get the data set
    dat <- get(input$file1)

    # Keep the selected columns
    dat <- dat[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]

    # Return first 20 rows
    head(dat, 20)
  })


})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application 
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Subset a table"),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv')),

      uiOutput("choose_columns")
      ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("data_table")
    )
  )
))
```

I'm getting following error while displaying tableOutput("data_table")

```
Error : invalid first argument
```

Comment: put a `print(input$columns)` before your `head(dat, 20)` statement to see if the correct columns are selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a `reactive` on your `dInput` and added one more on your filtered data. You can then use `data_table()` (with the `()`) for further operations. The (single file) code below works fine on my machine. I also remove the `observe` (useless) and changed what `dInput` returns (the actual file rather than colnames).

```
    library(shiny)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dInput <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    else
      return(read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=TRUE, sep=',',quote="'"))
  })


  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({
    cn <- colnames(dInput())
    selectInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
           choices  = cn,
           selected = cn,
           size=10,
           multiple=TRUE, selectize=FALSE)
  })

  data_table <- reactive({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    if(is.null(input$file1))
      return(NULL)

    # Get the data set
    dat <- dInput()

    # Keep the selected columns
    dat[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]
  })

  output$data_table <- renderTable(data_table())

})


# Define UI for application 
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Subset a table"),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv')),

      uiOutput("choose_columns")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h3("Filtered table"),
      tableOutput("data_table")
    )
  )
))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

is that what you want?

Comment: tried this but no change in output.. Am I missing on something ?

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much