# reading in CSVs according to ui input selection

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having trouble reading in `.csv` files dynamically based on ui input.

I have observations of precipitation and temperature data for different areas (ID'd here as `zone`). For a subset of those same areas, I also have frequency data of elevation observations. The app is meant as a CDF plotter of these three measurements for a region with many areas.

The problem is the elevation frequency data is much higher resolution than the precipitation and temperature data (together as `p_t`) and my code is too inefficient for good Shiny performance whenever users select elevation data (`elev`).

Instead of making one globally available filterable `data.frame` of all the data, I'm hoping to have Shiny go and grab individual `.csv`s of the frequency elevation data on the fly for just the area(s) that are selected in `input$zone` (via `SelectizeInput`). Once they're read in,  `uncount()` so they're in observation format, then bundle together into one `data.frame` `data()` with any precipitation or temperature (observation) data that's selected, for `ggplot`'s handy `stat_ecdf()` function with aesthetics set to `data()$param` and `data()$zone`.

Does this sound like an OK approach? If so, could you help me?  In summary the main need is, if the parameter `elev` is selected, have Shiny find and read in those elevation `.csv`s whose file names match the areas selected. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


# generate sample observation data - precipitation and temperature
# not many megabytes so will just read in all at once at startup as one .csv

zone <- c(rep("abcde", 6), rep("fghij", 6), rep("klmno", 6), 
rep("pqrst", 6))
set.seed(1)
val <- rnorm(24, 12, 18)
param <- rep(c("p", "t"), 12)
p_t <- data.frame(zone, val, param, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#head(p_t)
#   zone        val param
#1 abcde  0.7238314     p
#2 abcde 15.3055798     t
#3 abcde -3.0413150     p
#4 abcde 40.7150544     t
#5 abcde 17.9311399     p
#6 abcde -2.7684309     t

# generate sample elevation frequency data with many more observations - 
# need to be stored as individual .csvs, too big to read in, uncount, and 
# filter by input - too slow
# just want to bind and uncount as they're selected by user


setwd(./elevdata) # separate folder from which to pick out the elev data .csv in the main wd
# and prevent reading in of other app .csv data
val <- c(503, 506, 513, 689)
count <- c(32282, 53172, 45237, 34534)
data.frame(val, count) %>% mutate(zone = "abcde", param = "elev") %>% 
                      write_csv("abcde.csv")
val <- c(-36, -39, -51, -98)
count <- c(52220, 5175, 299237, 100034)
data.frame(val, count) %>% mutate(zone = "fghij", param = "elev") %>% 
                       write_csv("fghij.csv")
val <- c(2, 7, 13, 110)
count <- c(99222, 883172, 114237, 8347633)
data.frame(val, count) %>% mutate(zone = "klmno", param = "elev") %>% 
                       write_csv("klmno.csv")

#only a subset of p_t zones have elev data - variable not currently used
#zoneswithelevdata <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv$") 
#zoneswithelevdata <- gsub(".csv", "", zoneswithelevdata)


#shiny app using the above sample data

 shinyApp(

ui = fluidPage(

sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(

  selectizeInput(
    "zone", "zone", choices = unique(p_t$zone),
    selected = c("a"),
    multiple = TRUE),

  checkboxGroupInput("param", "parameter",
                     choices = c("elev", "p", "t"), selected =c("elev", "p"))
),

mainPanel(

  tabsetPanel(position=c("right"),

              tabPanel(strong("static cdf"), 
                       br(),
                       plotOutput("reg_plot",  height = "750px"))    )))

),

server = function(input, output) {

# elev_csv_counts_tobind <- reactive({ 
# if `elev` parameter is checked:
#* read_csv() of the csv(s) with csv file name %in% input$zone ** 
# * and bind together
#})

data <- reactive({

  p_t_e <- p_t %>%
   #first subset p_t by the zone(s) and param(s) selected      
   filter(param %in% input$param,
           zone %in% input$zone)   %>%
  #now attach and uncount the elevation data
    bind_rows({elev_csv_counts_tobind %>%
        uncount(count)})                       
})

output$reg_plot <- renderPlot({

  ggplot(data(), aes(val, color = param, linetype = zone)) +
    labs(y = "proportion of total", x = NULL) +
    stat_ecdf(pad = FALSE)  + coord_flip()
})
}  
)
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds very feasible. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36232774/7050882 for relevant hints. Beyond that, a series of nested `if`s would be needed in `server`, involving `input$param` and `input$zone`.